# MVC Code First using Navigation Properties

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ef-code-first, navigation-properties

It is a simple system for comments and messages. They have also two actors: FromActor and ToActor... My codes are like this:

```
 public class Comment
 {        
    public int Id { get; set; } 
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public virtual Actor AboutActor { get; set; }        
    public virtual Actor FromActor { get; set; }
 }

 public class Message
 {
    public int Id { get; set; }       
    public string Title { get; set; }       
    public string Text { get; set; }       
    public virtual Actor ToActor { get; set; }
    public virtual Actor FromActor { get; set; } 
}

public class Actor  
{       
    public int Id { get; set; }       
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Message> Messages { get; set; }
}
```

I'm in trouble with navigation props in code first. Is it true? How should I edit navigation links or models for solution? Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add additional references to `Comment`s and `Message`s at `Actor` class and use `InversePropertyAttribute` to map them with corresponding properties. Also you can declare `FK`s directly:

```
public class Comment
{        
    //other stuff...
    public int AboutActorId { get; set; }        
    public int FromActorId { get; set; }
    public virtual Actor AboutActor { get; set; }        
    public virtual Actor FromActor { get; set; }
}

public class Message
{
    //other stuff...
    public int ToActorId { get; set; }        
    public int FromActorId { get; set; }
    public virtual Actor ToActor { get; set; }
    public virtual Actor FromActor { get; set; } 
}

public class Actor  
{       
    public int Id { get; set; }       
    public string Username { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("AboutActor")]
    public virtual ICollection<Comment> CommentsAbout { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("FromActor")]
    public virtual ICollection<Comment> CommentsFrom { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("ToActor")]
    public virtual ICollection<Message> MessagesTo { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("FromActor")]
    public virtual ICollection<Message> MessagesFrom { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: With all my respect... Thanks a lot :) InverseProperty is my solution.